# How to visualize firebase data for analytical purpose?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For traditional back-ends, you usually have a relational database you can run SQL queries and visualize data to make decisions.

What's a good way to achieve this with firebase, the only thing that comes to mind is running raw JS from a node REPL.